# How can I make these panels fluid with 100% height without giving fixed height

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to make these panels take full length of container they are in, without providing fixed height, initially I want them to take all of the height of the page,

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0fgnu99o/10/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <h3 style="display: inline-block;">{{vm.Title}}</h3>
      <h4 class="pull-right" style="margin-top: 20px;">Back</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">
          <h4 class="panel-title">Panel 1</h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel2">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo">
          <h4 class="panel-title">Panel 2</h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" data-parent="#accordion" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.panel-heading a:after {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  content: "\e114";
  float: right;
}

.panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
  content: "\e080";
}

#collapseOne,
#collapseTwo {
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I don't want to provide this,

```
height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
```

Comment: I don't get what you really want. Do you want to have your panels some small height so both can fit on screen (one under another) and to the content inside them to be scrollable ?

Comment: not sure I understood your question but i updated the jsfiddle... kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/0fgnu99o/4/

Comment: This is what I mean. http://i.imgur.com/fbRk0jd.png

Comment: We coded the same example :D Do you have a problem when its opening ? When it stretches and returns?

Comment: @Please Tech, to achieve what you said in you edit 

**add**
~data-parent="#accordion"~
to collapseOne and collapse

updated fiddle as per your edit
https://jsfiddle.net/0fgnu99o/5/

Comment: how about using vh instead of px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use % in css for width and height from root element to all child elements while working on fluid layout, anyways here is a small jQuery tweak to achieve what you have asked, i hope this helps..:)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var $offHeight = 0

  function updateHeight() {
    var $tempHeight = 0;
    var $wrapper = $('.mainContainer');
    $tempHeight += $('.row').not('.mainRow').outerHeight();
    $tempHeight += $('#panel1').find('.panel-heading').outerHeight();
    $tempHeight += $('#panel2').find('.panel-heading').outerHeight() + 5 + 4; // +5 for margin-top of panel 2 header and +4 for adjustment 
    $offHeight = $wrapper.height() - $tempHeight;
    $('#collapseOne').css({

      'max-height': $offHeight
    });
    $('#collapseTwo').css({

      'max-height': $offHeight
    });



  }

  updateHeight();


  $('.panel-heading').on('click', function() {

    updateHeight();



  });

  $(window).resize(function() {


    updateHeight();

  });


});
```

```css
/*make parent of "container" fixed width and height*/

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
/*fill "container" to its parent width and height*/

.mainContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
/*extra margin-bottom fix*/

#accordion {
  margin: 0
}
.panel-heading a:after {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  content: "\e114";
  float: right;
}
.panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
  content: "\e080";
}
#collapseOne,
#collapseTwo {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container mainContainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <h3 style="display: inline-block;">{{vm.Title}}</h3>
      <h4 class="pull-right" style="margin-top: 20px;">Back</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mainRow">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">
          <h4 class="panel-title">Panel 1</h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Panel 1<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
          </li>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel2">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo">
          <h4 class="panel-title">Panel 2</h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" data-parent="#accordion" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Panel 2<i class="pull-right">Delete</i>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ajrycq33/1/

Comment: Hi mike, thanks for your answer, even though this is not what exactly I wanted but it will work for me, can you add a jsfiddle please so I could quickly test it and give you the bounty which will be wasted in an hour, thanks for your help

Comment: thanks mike, it seems like working properly, I am accepting your answer, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood what you want.

When you set height on a collapsing element, Bootstrap JS overrides it with it's style animation.

The solution I found is setting the `max-height`

```
.panel-collapse{
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[Check My Example](https://jsfiddle.net/1df596z7/15/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope here is what you have in mind..

https://jsfiddle.net/0fgnu99o/6/

```
code
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to look ok ...

```
.panel { height: 300px; }

#collapseOne, #collapseTwo {
  height:90%;
  max-height:90%;
  overflow-y:auto;

}
```

... to use % heights properly you need to specify a height for the parent.

EDIT:

It is however also valid to say that the parent .panel has height: 100%; but at some point in the stack unless you go all the way up to the html tag with height: 100% you will need to have an element with a fixed height so the browser can compute the height correctly

EDIT 2:

Upon further discussion with you in the chat it's more than likely that this is what you need ...

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#fillspace

Comment: I am trying jquery UI accordin as suggested but it's not fluid, it doesn't takes all of the height and isn't responsive (I can use JS for that but I want out of box solution for this scenario) http://jsfiddle.net/r4Lzsmhf/2/

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to support Opera Mini you should be able to use `vh` and possibly `calc`. You'll want to play with it yourself and tweak the numbers, but I think something like this should work (change from the current targets to these):

```
#panel1, #panel2 {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 150px);
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Edit: Just for clarity, `vh` refers to 'viewport height', so it's specific to the viewport of the end user's device and `calc` allows you to let the browser handle some simple math. If you know that certain other elements take a fixed number of pixels, you can subtract them from the viewport height and stay within the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you are looking for full height. Anyway this will remove scrollbar for contents. Please let me know.

```
#collapseOne, #collapseTwo {
height: auto;
max-height: none;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Flexbox (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

This has lots of possibilities to make sure 2 containers are the same heights

Answer (score -1):

If you only remove property **max-height** from panel element, parent is going to spread all the way down.

```
#collapseOne, #collapseTwo {
 overflow-y:auto;  
}
```

Fiddle: [CLICK](https://jsfiddle.net/0fgnu99o/13/)